# How to Cache flask function results

Tags: python, caching, flask

I want to cache the results of a flask function which is called by an event on my Website:

This is the function on flask:

```py
@app.route('/request_hourly_prediction')
def request_hourly_prediction():
    number = request.args.get('s_num')

    # do some stuff...
    # return jsonify(results)
```

And this is how is called by the website:

```
function func3(x) {
    $.getJSON(ROOT + '/request_hourly_prediction?s_num=' + x, null, function(data1) {
    // do stuff...
}
```

As you can see, I pass an argument to the function using `request.args.get('s_num')` I want to cache the results of the function based on the argument I pass: I tried with `@lru_cache(maxsize=32)` but it cache the function result regardless of the argument given.

I also saw some decorator functions that holds the results based on the arguments passed to a python function but the problem in this case is that I'm not actually passing any arguments inside the function call but I'm getting them from inside the function using `request.args.get('s_num')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
@app.route('/request_hourly_prediction')
def request_hourly_prediction():
    number = request.args.get('s_num')
    return jsonify(compute(number))

@lru_cache(maxsize=32)
def compute(number):
  # do computation
  return results
```

You could probably also put the `jsonify` inside `compute` if you wanted.

Comment: This works in debugging, but in a production environment multiple processes are typically spawned to handle the requests, so you end up with unexpected cache misses and data duplication.